# Sound Design: any sound effects library with rolling ball bearing sounds?

Tags: sound-design, foley

Does anyone know of a sound effects pack or website that contains a decent set of rolling ball bearing/hardball (e.g marbles etc.) sounds? I'm specifically looking for a ball rolling along a small metal track, like the ones you find inside some pinball machines.

Any suggestions would be helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: https://collectedtransients.com/product/rotation/ - you may check this library. It contains sounds of many rolling/rotating objects.

Answer (score 0):

record rolling a marble with variable speed on a fairly damped wooden board .then on the edit replace the hits with metal rings n other elements.

Comment: Cool idea. What do you mean by recording on variable speed?

Comment: My guess is to speed back the playback (can do in Audacity) which should make the surfaces sound brighter, more metallic. But really, ball bearings are cheap, and easy to record. I'd be tempted to just "roll my own".

Answer (score 0):

The Boom library has "spinning glass" and "spinning plastic" which might do part of the job. The impacts you can add from a metal impact sound.

Answer (score 0):

HISSandROAR contact mic library will do the trick.
http://hissandaroar.com/sd008-contact-mic/

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would just record it. Assuming you have the gear. Chances are you wouldn't find a 'rolling marbles' library as it's too specific a sound. I'd try a website like sound dogs that might have what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Splice.com](http://splice.com) has lots of foley stuff. Here are a few with marbles and ball bearings:

- [Marbles](https://splice.com/sounds/blastwave-fx/bw-foley-vol-3?q=marbles)
- [Ball bearings](https://splice.com/sounds/blastwave-fx/bw-foley-vol-1?q=ball)

Answer (score 0):

This library should do the trick, with all things spinning & rolling: https://www.asoundeffect.com/sound-library/rolling-spinning/

Answer (score 0):

I just searched on youtube "marble rolling on iron".

Alternatively you can also make it synthetically by creating a white noise, filtering it with an eq, using a bit crusher on it and then some ring filter like demonstrated here